# Accessing Google API data from within 3 async callbacks and a function in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, asynchronous, swiftui, google-api, callback

I know this question is asked a lot, but I can't figure out how to apply any answers to *my* program. Sorry in advance this `async` stuff makes absolutely zero sense to me.

Basically, I have a button in `SwiftUI` that, when pressed, calls a function that makes two API calls to Google Sheets using `Alamofire` and `GoogleSignIn`.

```
Button("Search") {
    if fullName != "" {
        print(SheetsAPI.nameSearch(name: fullName, user: vm.getUser()) ?? "Error")
    }
}
```

This function should return the values of some cells on success or `nil` on an error. However, it only ever prints out `"Error"`. Here is the function code.

```
static func nameSearch<S: StringProtocol>(name: S, advisory: S = "", user: GIDGoogleUser?) -> [String]? {
    let name = String(name)
    let advisory = String(advisory)
    let writeRange = "'App Control'!A2:C2"
    let readRange = "'App Control'!A4:V4"
    
    // This function can only ever run when user is logged in, ! should be fine?
    let user = user!
    
    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "range": writeRange,
        "values": [
            [
                name,
                nil,
                advisory
            ]
        ]
    ]
    
    // What I want to be returned
    var data: [String]?
    
    // Google Identity said use this wrapper so that the OAuth tokens refresh
    user.authentication.do { authentication, error in
        guard error == nil else { return }
        guard let authentication = authentication else { return }
        
        // Get the access token to attach it to a REST or gRPC request.
        let token = authentication.accessToken
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
        
        AF.request("url", method: .put, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseString { response in
            
            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                // I assume there is a better way to make two API calls...
                AF.request("anotherURL", headers: headers).responseDecodable(of: NameResponseModel.self) { response2 in
                    
                    switch response2.result {
                    case .success:
                        guard let responseData = response2.value else { return }
                        data = responseData.values[0]
                        // print(responseData.values[0]) works fine
                        
                    case .failure:
                        print(response2.error ?? "Unknown error.")
                        data = nil
                        
                    }
                }
                
            case .failure:
                print(response.error ?? "Unknown error.")
                data = nil
            }
        }
    }
    // Always returns nil, "Unknown error." never printed
    return data
}
```

The model struct for my second AF request:

```
struct NameResponseModel: Decodable { let values: [[String]] }
```

An example API response for the second AF request:

```
{
  "range": "'App Control'!A4:V4",
  "majorDimension": "ROWS",
  "values": [
    [
      "Bob Jones",
      "A1234",
      "Cathy Jones",
      "1234 N. Street St. City, State 12345"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I saw stuff about your own callback function as a function parameter (or something along those lines) to handle this, but I was completely lost. I also looked at Swift `async`/`await`, but I don't know how that works with callback functions. Xcode had the option to refactor `user.authentication.do { authentication, error in` to `let authentication = try await user.authentication.do()`, but it threw a missing parameter error (the closure it previously had).

**EDIT: `user.authentication.do` also returns void--another reason the refactor didn't work (I think).**

There is probably a much more elegant way to do all of this so excuse the possibly atrocious way I did it.

[Here is the link to Google Identity Wrapper info.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/reference/Classes/GIDAuthentication?hl=en#-dowithfreshtokens:)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Network calls take time to make a request. You’re returning nil right away. Best to avoid nested network calls with async await approach.

Comment: @cora made an edit. even if i did unnest them, how would i access the refreshed token without them being inside the auth callback? or is there a way to use async/await even though it returns void?

Comment: Here is a good read https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/deciding-what-queue-to-run-a-completion-handler-on/

Comment: @cora thanks, i read it. but i cant figure out how to implement what it says into my code to fix the problem. Unfortunately this is one of those code concepts I just don't understand.

Comment: I suggest you read-up on `asynchronous` functions and completion handler.
Re-structure your functions, eg, `nameSearch` with such a completion handler. Alternatively, there is also 
the Swift async/await concurency framework that you can use to deal with your 
 asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.

It appears (according to [Apple's `async/await` intro video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021-10132/?time=1666)) that when you have an unsupported callback that you need to run asynchronously, you wrap it in something called a `Continuation`, which allows you to manually `resume` the function on the thread, whether `throwing` or `returning`.

So using that code allows you to run the Google Identity token refresh with `async/await`.

```
private static func auth(_ user: GIDGoogleUser) async throws -> GIDAuthentication? {
    typealias AuthContinuation = CheckedContinuation<GIDAuthentication?, Error>
        
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: AuthContinuation) in
        user.authentication.do { authentication, error in
            if let error = error {
                continuation.resume(throwing: error)
            } else {
                continuation.resume(returning: authentication)
            }
        }
    }
}

static func search(user: GIDGoogleUser) async throws {

    // some code

    guard let authentication = try await auth(user) else { ... }

    // some code
}
```

I then ran that before using [Alamofire's built-in `async/await` functionality](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/AdvancedUsage.md#using-alamofire-with-swift-concurrency) for each request (here's one).

```
let dataTask = AF.request(...).serializingDecodable(NameResponseModel.self)
let response = try await dataTask.value

return response.values[0]
```